# Can SimpleSchema express "object with custom keys and specific schema for values"?

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

I want to make a [SimpleSchema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) for documents with the the following format:

```
{
  ...,
  permissions: {
    foo: {allow: ["user1", "user2"]},
    bar: {allow: ["admin"]},
  }
}
```

If `foo` and `bar` were well-known strings in the schema, I would just do this:

```
const PermissionsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  allow: {type: [String]},
});

new SimpleSchema({
  ...,
  'permissions.foo': {
    type: PermissionSchema,
  },
  'permissions.bar': {
    type: PermissionSchema,
  },
})
```

However, in this case, there can be arbitrary string keys, not just `foo` and `bar`. The values must always match `PermissionsSchema`. Is there a way to express this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Custom validators](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#custom-validation) to the rescue!

```
import { ValidationError } from 'mdg:validation-error';

function permissionsValidator(keyRegEx) {
  if (!(keyRegEx instanceof RegExp)) {
    throw new Error('must pass a regular expression');
  }
  return function() {
    // https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#custom-validation
    const value = this.value;
    for (let key in value) {
      if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (!keyRegEx.test(key)) {
          return 'regEx';
        }
        try {
          PermissionSchema.validate(value[key]);
        } catch (ex) {
          if (ex instanceof ValidationError) {
            return ex.error;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
}

new SimpleSchema({
  ...,
  permissions: {
    type: Object,
    custom: permissionsValidator(/^.*$/),
    blackbox: true,
    optional: true,
    defaultValue: {},
  },
});
```

The error messages that come out are rubbish, though. Improvements or better strategies still welcome.