# simpl-schema: How to create an schema that validates every property of an object is of a certain schema?

Tags: meteor, simpl-schema

Basically... I have something of the following type: `record<string, User>` (aka `Map<String,User>`). Basically, an object that can have any field, as long as it is an user.

How do I create an Schema that validates that?

Answer (score 0):

There is an older question that seems to ask the same thing [Can SimpleSchema express "object with custom keys and specific schema for values"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781972/can-simpleschema-express-object-with-custom-keys-and-specific-schema-for-values) , however being asked for an older version of this library.

The accepted answer assumes the usage of Custom Validators

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/longshotlabs/simpl-schema#type

> Another SimpleSchema instance, meaning Object type with this schema

```js
const userSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    // For accounts-password, either emails or username is required, but not both. It is OK to make this
    // optional here because the accounts-password package does its own validation.
    // Third-party login packages may not require either. Adjust this schema as necessary for your usage.
    optional: true,
  },
  emails: {
    type: Array,
    // For accounts-password, either emails or username is required, but not both. It is OK to make this
    // optional here because the accounts-password package does its own validation.
    // Third-party login packages may not require either. Adjust this schema as necessary for your usage.
    optional: true,
  },
  'emails.$': {
    type: Object,
  },
  'emails.$.address': {
    type: String,
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email,
  },
  'emails.$.verified': {
    type: Boolean,
  },
  // Use this registered_emails field if you are using splendido:meteor-accounts-emails-field / splendido:meteor-accounts-meld
  registered_emails: {
    type: Array,
    optional: true,
  },
  'registered_emails.$': {
    type: Object,
    blackbox: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
  },
  profile: {
    type: Schema.UserProfile,
    optional: true,
  },
  // Make sure this services field is in your schema if you're using any of the accounts packages
  services: {
    type: Object,
    optional: true,
    blackbox: true,
  },
  // DISCLAIMER: This only applies to the first and second version of meteor-roles package.
  // https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-collection2/issues/399
  // Add `roles` to your schema if you use the meteor-roles package.
  // Option 1: Object type
  // If you specify that type as Object, you must also specify the
  // `Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP` group whenever you add a user to a role.
  // Example:
  // Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, ["admin"], Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP);
  // You can't mix and match adding with and without a group since
  // you will fail validation in some cases.
  roles: {
    type: Object,
    optional: true,
    blackbox: true,
  },
  // Option 2: [String] type
  // If you are sure you will never need to use role groups, then
  // you can specify [String] as the type
  roles: {
    type: Array,
    optional: true,
  },
  'roles.$': {
    type: String,
  },
  // In order to avoid an 'Exception in setInterval callback' from Meteor
  heartbeat: {
    type: Date,
    optional: true,
  },
});

const someOtherSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  useDocument: {
    type: userSchema
  },
});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. It just validates a document with the field 'useDocument', that is a user. I need a validator that checks that I have an object in which EVERY FIELD, (whatever field it is), is an user

Comment: @AlejandroNavas  Harry is trying to help. Why don't you make an effort yourself, and show the code you have tried?